# Blocks in non-trivial cycles

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I read following [article](http://albertodebortoli.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/objective-c-blocks-caveat/) but i am a little bit confused with following paragraph.

> Apple documentation says that “For non-trivial cycles, however, you should use” this approach:

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init…];
// ...
MyViewController * __weak weakMyController = myController;
myController.completionHandler =  ^(NSInteger result) {
    MyViewController *strongMyController = weakMyController;
    if (strongMyController) {
        // ...
        [strongMyController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        // ...
    }
    else {
        // Probably nothing...
    }
};
```

> First of all, this example looks wrong to me. How can self be
>   deallocated and be nilled out if the block itself is retained in the
>   completionHandler property? The completionHandler property can be
>   declared as assign or unsafe_unretained to allow the object to be
>   deallocated after the block is passed around. I can’t see the reason
>   for doing that. If other objects need the object (self), the block
>   that is passed around should retain the object and therefore the block
>   should not be assigned to a property. No _*weak/*_strong usage should
>   be involved in this case.

1. He says that "if other objects need the object (self):"
   What does he mean by **need** here? Is it something like this: They need self because they access the block(block passed to them) which needs the self, so they need self. If not what does he mean?
2. Then he says that "therefore the block should not be assigned to a property."
   But what if there are multiples of objects that need the block some undefined time in future? So, we could pass the block to them through getting from this property.

Am i taking things wrong way?

Comment: I think this article is confusing things. The block in this example doesn't *need* `self` (btw, I have to assume that by `self` they mean `myController`). The whole point of using `weakMyController` is not retaining, and therefore not needing, `self`. By "non-trivial blocks" Apple means a block where the weak reference is used more than once. In that case you usually want that reference to be valid for the duration of the block. That is the reason of having `MyViewController *strongMyController = weakMyController;`

Comment: While I understand why Alberto struggled with that poor example from Apple's documentation, his diagnosis of the problem and his analysis of potential remedies is flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article's author is a little bit confused, and has gotten some things backwards.

> How can self be deallocated and be nilled out if the block itself is
>   retained in the completionHandler property?

If the block is retained in the `completionHandler`, that means `self` has a strong reference to the block, which means the block is alive as long as `self` is -- not the other way around. That `self` retains the block has nothing to do with `self` being deallocated or not.

> The completionHandler property can be declared as assign or
>   unsafe_unretained to allow the object to be deallocated after the
>   block is passed around.

Again, whether `completionHandler` is a strong or weak reference affects the block's lifetime. It has nothing to do with the object pointed to by `self`'s lifetime.

> If other objects need the object (self), the block that is passed
>   around should retain the object and therefore the block should not be
>   assigned to a property.

No. The object retains the block. The block does not retain the object.

Whether the pattern shown in the code sample is needed in most circumstances is very debatable. However, the author's reasoning is wrong.

Comment: I clearly haven't been clear in my article and I apologize for that.

Comment: Some sentences were poorly composed and in fact I do agree with your explanations.
About your 3 quotes, those were the worst, confusing and most unnecessary considerations of mine.
I've just updated the article on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks retain the variables mentioned within them so they can execute in the context where they first appeared.  You get a cycle when one of those retained block variables retains the block either directly (trivial) or indirectly (non-trivial).

For example, when objectA owns a block that mentions objectA, we get a trivial cycle:  objectA -> block -> objectA.

```
// objectA owns a block property (declared as copy) called theBlock
objectA.theBlock = ^{
    // anything in the current scope can be mentioned safely in here, except:
    [objectA doSomething];
};
```

The article's advice should be to break the retain cycle by using an unretained copy of objectA's pointer in the block...

```
__unsafe_unretained ObjectAType *objectAUnretainedCopy = objectA;
// in an ARC project, @Rob points out that this is probably better qualified as __weak
objectA.theBlock = ^{
    // now we can mention anything in the current scope, including:
    [objectAUnretainedCopy doSomething];
};
```

Now objectA still retains the block, but this improved block does not retain objectA.

A non-trivial cycle is the same, just with a longer chain of ownership that makes the cycle tougher to recognize.  Say objectB keeps a retained (strong) pointer to objectA...

```
objectB.myObjectA = objectA;
```

Now it's wrong to mention objectB in objectA's block, because you end up with a cycle:
objectB -> objectA -> theBlock -> objectB.

```
objectA.theBlock = ^{
    // anything in the current scope can be mentioned safely in here, except:
    [objectB doSomething];
};
```

The same solution applies.  Don't refer directly to objectB, instead use an unretained copy...

```
__unsafe_unretained ObjectBType *objectBUnretainedCopy = objectB;
// again, per @Rob, or __weak
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you're advising `__unsafe_unretained` versus the `__weak` advocated by that article. I can see no advantage in this scenario to `__unsafe_unretained`, and I can contrive implementations of `ObjectA` where it can get you into trouble (and it seems like we don't want to write code contingent on internal implementation details of `ObjectA`). It just seems more prudent to just use `__weak`.

Comment: I picked up the habit using blocks pre-ARC.  I guess it would be better to change to weak. (Though I can't think of a contrivance where it would break).  I skimmed the article, and didn't find it particularly lucid.  Seems like cycles should be simpler to describe and simpler to cure than the author implied.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. If you want to see example of how you can end up with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` using `__unsafe_unretained` in this example, let me know (though we might want to move it to chat). And while it requires a bit of a contrivance in this case (partially because of the cognitive dissonance of Apple's example code that Alberto (unsatisfactorily) wrestled with), in many practical real-world scenarios, the `__unsafe_unretained` approach can easily cause problems that the `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern simply avoids.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following blog, it is making some sense. It is explaining it in a more better way.

https://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/

Comment: The article is good but it doesn't go into enough detail to help the OP. This article is much better: http://www.logicsector.com/ios/avoiding-objc-retain-cycles-with-weakself-and-strongself-the-easy-way/ "because Clang may decide to re-evaluate object retention on a statement-by-statement basis"

Comment: I agree http://www.logicsector.com/ios/avoiding-objc-retain-cycles-with-weakself-and-strongself-the-easy-way/ is better to explain the "strong/weak dance" as it is called...